# Combining two models, one having an iterator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, merge, splitting, loop

I have two different ModelBuilder models:

1. Create a new field and split a layer
2. Merge all layers in one folder

I want to append both models in one but it does not work.

The Model have a loop and I do not know why and how to solve it.

Could you help me?

[image: Model Builder screen capture]

Answer (score 1):

The loop is being caused by your iterator.

You need to create a [sub model](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/integrating-model-within-a-model.htm).

Model 1 will be everything up to & including your Split tool.

Model 2 will start at your Feature Iterator.

Comment: I would create model 1 as a sub-model. Then you have sub models 1 and 2 as you described sitting in the master model; model 1 connecting to model 2 and the output of model 2 feeding into the merge tool.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. That's true that the iterator must be at first of everything. I will try that you said :)